# Usage of "unbelievably likely"

Tags: phrases, oxymoron

When listening to BBC commentary of a World Cup game last week, I stumbled upon the expression used by the commentator. In my ears, to describe something as "unbelievably likely" is a contradiction in terms as the probability that something happens makes it either unbelievable and thus unlikely or, then, likely. What do you think?

Comment: Hi medica – thank you, and welcome to this thread. My question concerns the use of the two terms on an abstract level, if you will (although both words have an unbelievably concrete meaning and I find it likely that in an ensuing discussion an answer will eventually result).

Comment: So you aren't interested in the actual instance from the BBC commentary? If you do a search of the term, you will see that it does turn up. For example, 'It really is unbelievably likely the up coming form of the apple iphone will look like the images', where 'unbelievingly' means 'amazingly'. I agree that we need to keep this focussed.

Comment: Thank you, medica and Peter. In fact, I forgot the original quote and really only remember that particular calamity. I can, of course, invent a quote – se non è vero, è ben trovato: «England was unbelievably likely to bow out early.» But please do not feel compelled to restrict your answer/discussion to that particular phrase.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I assume that it would thus be wrong to employ 'unbelievably' here in its proper sense and that it would be bad taste to use it in the sense of 'very'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase isn't meaningless or oxymoronic, as likelihood is not a matter of belief and so might contradict it.  For example, an engineer might perform an analysis of an engine and find that it has a 90% chance of exploding, which is far higher than she would have believed; it is therefore "unbelievably likely" to explode.

I suspect that "unbelievably" is being used here to mean "impressively" or "extremely", which is a common usage although, to my mind, one to avoid.  "Unbelievably likely" may just mean "you won't believe how likely it is".  Football commentators are notorious in the UK for comically awkward turns of phrase, perhaps even to the point of deliberately playing it up at times.